# Cannot connect cluster mongo.db atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I'm currently trying to learn MEAN stack. The tutorial are about a task manager. Right now I'm trying to connect to mongodb atlas to retrieve sample data in database but they are not showing up http://localhost:3000/api/tasks

Here is my tasks.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('drivers',['tasks']);


router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
    db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(tasks);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var task = require('./routes/tasks');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', task);

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server started on port' +port);
});
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "mytasklist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Task Manager",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongojs": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error displayed? The link to the route should be http://localhost:3000/tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I pasted the wrong version for my nodejs driver.

Answer (score 0):

need to use mongojs version 3.0.0 to connect to atlas